# How to get listeners of Picasso in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

i'm  currently working with kotlin and i'm  using Picasso to show pictures, so... I need to know how to set a listener to Picasso to know when it finishs.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Picasso. The [Picasso.Listener](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/4110/index.html) interface only reports when an image fails to load. There is another library called Glide which [provides this functionality](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/4110/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll try it